# Qt creator: qmake is not recognized

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I am trying to understand 'qmake' by following [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-tutorial.html) . but when I come the the following command:

```
qmake -o Makefile hello.pro
```

my command line console shows me this message:

```
'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I understood that qmake is part of Qt creator and thus it should be executed whenever I run it within my project's folder. so, why it is not recognized ?

Comment: Which operating system you are using and how did you installed Qt?

Comment: @user2228947: I am using windows Vista and I downloaded and installed Qt from [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads)

Comment: @user2228947: I know how to add paths in my system variables, but what I don't know is where qmake file is located. is it on my project's folder (but hidden) or is it within the Qt installation directory ? ..

Comment: @user2228947: thank you .. I found it in my Qt installation directory in \bin folder .. now, after adding the path to my environment variable, it is working  (you can put you comment as an an answer for me to accept it .. thank you )

Comment: @hashDefine I followed exactly what you did but I don't have a /bin folder in the QT installation directory.. Where did you get that !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, you can add path to qmake to PATH or run qmake from directory where it placed, or use absolute path.

Comment: Qmake doesn't exist, how can i install it?

Answer (score 4):

In the start menu entry that was created by the installer for Qt, you should find an item that opens a command prompt with all the needed environment variables (including the PATH) already set.  For my Qt 5.0.2 install using MingW, it is called "Qt 5.0.2 for Desktop (MinGW 4.7)".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my friend, i don´t speak English very well.

In Qt 5.10.1 I resolved this problem running the command prompt in the next path, C:\Qt\5.10.1\mingw53_32>, after you need change the directory where is the file hello.pro and run the commnand qmake -o Makefile hello.pro after you can see the makefile in the respective folder.